# Write to CSV file where value is a dictionary, and value needs to be on same row as key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, export-to-csv

I have a dictionary output that looks like this:

```
{'2016-07': {'open': 2, 'closed': 14}, '2016-12': {'open': 14, 'closed': 37}}
```

I need to create a CSV file where each row looks like this:

```
2016-07, 2, 14
2016-12, 14, 37
```

Below is my writing to CSV method:

```
def send_to_csv():
    values = sort_by_year_month()
    with open('Issues_by_month.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
        file_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        file_writer.writerow(['Month',
                              'Opened Issues',
                              'Closed Issues',
                              ])
        for key, value in values.items():
            file_writer.writerow([key, value])
```

I think I just need to iterate over the value and then write them out, but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import csv

data = {
    '2016-07': {'open': 2, 'closed': 14},
    '2016-12': {'open': 14, 'closed': 37}
}

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(['Month',
                     'Opened Issues',
                     'Closed Issues'])
    # Get the date
    for date in sorted(data):
        row = [date]
        # Append each value to the row
        for key, value in data[date].items():
            row.append(value)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

**output.csv**

```
Month,Opened Issues,Closed Issues
2016-07,2,14
2016-12,14,37
```

Try it on [replit.it](https://repl.it/KCF2/1)

Answer (score 2):

To ensure the dates are sorted, try iterating over their sorted values:

```
for key in sorted(values.keys()):
    d = values[key]
    file_writer.writerow([key, d.get('open'), d.get('closed')])
```

Comment: So the above is almost working. the output is: `2015-07,open,closed` when I need the values from the open, close not the keys

Comment: `for key, value in values.items():
    open, close = value.values()`

Comment: @Deusdeorum Not quite... The keys may not be ordered by dates in ascending order.

Comment: @Alexander true, i was just assuming they were..but still, you're output is wrong as it will be `2017-07 open close`